# Excel macro to compare selected column cell to "next column" cell and color-fill if identical

Tags: vba, excel

I'd imagine that this must be very easy to do, but I simply can't find help with my GoogleFu, and I don't understand VBA's object reference guide thing.

What I'm trying to do is make a macro that allows me to select a column, then have each cell in that column compared - row by row - to the cell in the column to its right (e.g. A1:B1 if A1 is selected, F1:G1 is F1 is selected). I don't want a cell compared to all cells in a different column (e.g. A1 compared to all cells in column B), or to all cells in the same row (e.g. A1 compared to all cells in row A).

When I do this manually, I highlight two cells that I want to look at, click "Conditional formatting", do formatting by formula, and enter =x1<>y1 (where x1 is the column I'd select, e.g. A1 or F1, and y1 is the column I want to compare to, e.g. B1 or G1).

I tried using the macro recorder, but it's forcing me to specify columns by ID instead of allowing me to choose a column by selection with my mouse. If there's a way to make a textbox pop up that lets me type in the columns I want, that would work. It would also work if there's a way to populate the selected column as x1 and populate the column to its right as y1. I haven't been able to find info on either of those possibilities. I know that the .Offset property exists, but I don't know how it could be used for what I want.

Here's the code that came from my macro recorder:

```
    Sub ColorHighlightDiscrepancies()
'
' ColorHighlightDiscrepancies Macro
' ColorHighlightDiscrepancies
'

'
    Columns("X:Y").Select
    Range("Y1").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=X1<>Y1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 4145151
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Here's code that goes row-by-row (found at ExcelForum), but compares all cells within a row to all other cells within the row:

```
Sub ColorDuplicates()

  Dim Data As Variant
  Dim DSO As Object
  Dim Rng As Range

   'Assumes Row 1 has Column Headers
    Set Rng = Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
    Data = Rng.Value

    Set DSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

      For I = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        For J = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
          Key = Trim(Data(I, J))
          If Key <> "" Then
            If Not DSO.Exists(Key) Then
               DSO.Add Key, 1
            Else
               Rng.Cells(I, J).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
          End If
        Next J
        DSO.RemoveAll
      Next I

    Set DSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Either one works, really. My goal is just to make it clear which row entries have the same values vs different values (e.g. if row A has 300 and 300, whereas row B has 150 and 300).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there's a way to make a textbox pop up that lets me type in the columns I want, that would work.

**Fortunately, there is:**

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select column(s)", Type:=8)
```

**Alternatively:**

> I tried using the macro recorder, but it's forcing me to specify columns by ID instead of allowing me to choose a column by selection with my mouse.

Change this:

```
Columns("X:Y").Select
Range("Y1").Activate
```

To this (which will select the first cell in the second column of the current `Selection`):

```
Range(Selection.Cells(1, 2).Address).Activate
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for the second one. 

Runtime error 1004

"Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"

Comment: Ah crikey. The default property of a range is it's `.Value`, so that's the error. Change it to: `Range(Selection.Cells(1, 2).Address).Activate`

Comment: The first one works! Had to figure out how to use it. : ) Thank you!

Comment: Cheers. Do consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it's helped solve your problem :)

Comment: I don't know what's happening with the second one. After making the change you noted in the comments, it just colors everything red no matter what the values are. But that's ok, because the InputBox one works perfectly! Thanks again!